# How do I override Django's default admin templates and layouts

Tags: python, django

I am trying to override Django's default template. For now just the base_site.html. I'm trying to change the text django administration.

I did the following:

1. I created a folder in my app directory `/opt/mydjangoapp/templates/admin`
2. I then copied the original django admin templates folder contents into admin and here are the contents:
   *404.html        auth              change_list.html          delete_selected_confirmation.html  index.html           pagination.html              search_form.html
   500.html        base.html         change_list_results.html  edit_inline                        invalid_setup.html   popup_response.html          submit_line.html
   actions.html    base_site.html    date_hierarchy.html       filter.html                        login.html           prepopulated_fields_js.html
   app_index.html  change_form.html  delete_confirmation.html  includes                           object_history.html  related_widget_wrapper.html*
3. I changed the contents of `base_site.html`, so that I have the title '*My App Admin*' as opposed to '*Django Administration*'
4. My settings file looks as follows:

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = (
       'mydjangoapp',
       'django.contrib.admin',
       'django.contrib.auth',
       'django.contrib.contenttypes',
       'django.contrib.sessions',
       'django.contrib.messages',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles',
       'debug_toolbar',
   )

   ...

   TEMPLATES = [
       {
           'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
           'DIRS': ['/opt/mydjangoapp/templates/'],
           'OPTIONS': {
               'context_processors': [
                   'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                   'django.template.context_processors.request',
                   'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                   'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
               ],
               'debug':True,
               'loaders': (
                    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader'
               ),
           },
       },
   ]
   ```

But unfortunately, Django version 1.8 seems to be ignoring my template changes and loading the original template files. Any suggestions as to how I can override the original layout for the admin. Bare in mind changing the title is just the beginning of the changes that I want to perform?

Comment: Can you post your `INSTALLED_APPS` as well?

Comment: @PauloScardine here you go :-)
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'mydjangoapp',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'debug_toolbar',
)

Comment: Looks OK, your application is listed first... I suspect you must move the template folder inside your app (`/opt/mydjangoapp/mydjangoapp/templates/` instead of `/opt/mydjangoapp/templates/`). I guess `settings.TEMPLATES['DIRS']` are global templates not tied to any particular app so they will have the least priority.

Comment: @PauloScardine Thank you, that worked. Don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: @PauloScardine Perhaps add as answer so that i can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure your application is listed first, because Django always take the resources from the first application where it finds them, according to the order in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`.

In this case the app was listed first, but the override was not working because the templates were placed under the global template directories listed under `settings.TEMPLATES['DIRS']` which are not tied to any particular app and will have the least priority.

If this is your case, you must move the template folder inside your app (for example, `/opt/mydjangoapp/mydjangoapp/templates/` instead of `/opt/mydjangoapp/templates/`) and wipe the reference at `settings.TEMPLATES['DIRS']`.